# Mock static method that calls to external service

Tags: mockito

I have a class that has a static method that passes in request and that calls server to retrieve the response.
is there a  way to mock that since it unit test I do not want to make a service call.

```
String jsonResponse = getMeMyMoney(request)

protected static String getMeMyMoney(request)
{
response = executeService(request)
return response
}
```

I tried this which is supposed to bypass the method but it still went it. Any one knows how to do this

```
doReturn("1").when(TestClass.getMeMyMoney("S"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mock static methods with Mockito, it is also stated in [FAQ](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ).

Use [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/GettingStarted) on top of Mockito.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(TestClass.class);
when(TestClass.getMeMyMoney("S")).thenReturn("1");
```